# Use Location inside <ifModule mod_ntml.c>

Tags: apache, .htaccess, location, ntlm

I have configured my Apache Server with NTLM authentication as following:

```
<ifModule mod_ntlm.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all

    Allow from localhost
    Allow from x.x.x.x

    AuthName NTAuth
    AuthType NTLM
    NTLMAuth on
    NTLMAuthoritative on
    NTLMDomain SERVER
    NTLMServer xxx
    NTLMBackup xxx
    Require valid-user

    Satisfy any
</ifModule>
```

I would like to remove the NTLM authentication for a specific location. It holds files, which are not needed to be authenticated.

But using  inside of  produces an error. Any suggestions on how to solve my issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution while browsing through the various directories. I just added a file named ".htaccess" in the desired folder with the content "Allow from all".

Now it works as desired.